# Can't disable signature check for system app on android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to disable signature check for system app on my Android samsung Galaxy S2 with the cm 10.1 nightly rom, to develop an anti-theft app. So I've try [this solution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2198834), by decompiling Services.jar with [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1732635).

And after replacing the file and restarting, my phone "forgot" all my apps (only rom application was still here) and I cannot install other application (via usb debugging). So I try by editing the file directly in a new rom (zip) file, and the same problem appear.

Do you know where the problem can be ? Or maybe another way to install app with system signed app rights ?
Do we know the private key of cm ? So maybe I can sign my app with the key ? (but I we know this key, it is a security problem, so I don't think we can)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've check the logcat when the installation problem occur, and i have this error

```
"Cannot install platform packages to user storage"
```

I look into the cm github and i found this part of code

```
Signature[] s1 = null;
if (obj instanceof SharedUserSetting) {
    s1 = ((SharedUserSetting)obj).signatures.mSignatures;
}
if ((compareSignatures(pkg.mSignatures, s1) == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH)) {
    Slog.w(TAG, "Cannot install platform packages to user storage");
    mLastScanError = PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION;
    return null;
}
```

Previously, with the tutorial I've edit the `compareSignatures()` function to make it return `SIGNATURE_MATCH`. But in this code, the error occurs when the function return this value.

It's seem this code is a security added, to be sure a system app will not be installed in the "user storage". The only way to fix my problem was to make the error never append (and I don't think this is a big vulnerability, but maybe i'm wrong, and if you have a better solution tell me)

So in addition to the first tutorial, I've replace

```
invoke-static {v3, v0}, Lcom/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService;->compareSignatures([Landroid/content/pm/Signature;[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;)I

move-result v3

if-nez v3, :cond_1d1
.line 3715
const-string v3, "PackageManager"
const-string v4, "Cannot install platform packages to user storage"
invoke-static {v3, v4}, Landroid/util/Slog;->w(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

by

```
invoke-static {v3, v0}, Lcom/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService;->compareSignatures([Landroid/content/pm/Signature;[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;)I

const/4 v3, -0x3

if-nez v3, :cond_1d1
.line 3715
const-string v3, "PackageManager"
const-string v4, "Cannot install platform packages to user storage"
invoke-static {v3, v4}, Landroid/util/Slog;->w(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

And it work :) I've never work in decompiled Java bytecode before so if I've made some mistakes, tell me.

Hope it will help !

Comment: Would you please give me some more details? Which apk (or jar) to modify? Where is it?